# In Erased, why does Satoru refers to his mother as "okaasan"?

Tags: japanese-language, erased

In *Erased*, when Satoru got transported back to 1988, he mistakenly referred to his mother as "kaasan". However, when pointed out, he quickly switches to "okaasan". Why is that?

As far as I know people usually refer to their own mother as "kaasan", and not "okaasan" as Satoru did.

Comment: The initial o- (お-) prefix is an honorific prefix. It is used to show politeness to parents, but it’s not uncommon to hear “Kaasan” or “Tousan”. In more casual situations the speaker may omit this prefix.

Comment: Pointed out what? _Okaasan_ is quite common when talking to one's mother. I guess it is  more common than _kaasan_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you're referring to the following exchange (from [here](http://blog.livedoor.jp/kaigai_no/archives/47531380.html)).

> 悟　 ：あっ・・・母さん・・・(Ma・・・)
>
> 佐知：母さん？("Ma"？)
>
> 悟　 ：えっ？お・・・お母さんって言ったでしょ？(I said "Mom.")

In Japanese, a large majority of kids call their mother either *okaasan* or *mama*, depending simply on the custom of each family (and switch very rarely). A kid ( <12 years old, say) saying *kaasan* is relatively rare, that is why it sounded weird to the mother.

So Satoru apparently switched from *okaasan* to *kaasan* at some point when he grew older. He first used *kaasan* due to his 'current' (i.e., as a grown-up) habit, but it sounds unusual to the mother, then he 'corrected' it to *okaasan*, which should have been the way he called his mother.

---

If I remember correctly, Conan (or Shinichi) the detective called his mother *kaasan*, but he is 15 or 16 years old. As people grow older, use of *kaasan* becomes more common, while it is by no means strange that a 50-year-old man calls to his mother by *okaasan*.